# Floats are being rounded when I log?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I have a list of vector3's I noticed that sometimes the values will get rounded, but i'm not sure why.

I am using UnityEngine.Vector3.

```
 List<Vector3> verticiesList = new List<Vector3> { };
        
 verticiesList.Add(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.65f, 0));
 Debug.Log(verticiesList[0]);
```

The result of the log is `0.5,0.7,0.0`

how can i give the correct values to `mesh.vertices`?

I would like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: you can use `Debug.Log($"my point: {verticiesList[0].x:G9}, {verticiesList[0].y:G9}, {verticiesList[0].z:G9}");` to obtain all the decimals

Comment: The `ToString` method is implicitly called and from the source you can see how it is formatted https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs#L467

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes! Unity rounds them to be better readable.

From the [`Vector3` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs#L453)

> ```
> public override string ToString()
> {
>     return ToString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
> }
>
> public string ToString(string format)
> {
>     return ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
> }
>
> public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
> {
>     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
>         format = "F1";
>     return UnityString.Format("({0}, {1}, {2})", x.ToString(format, formatProvider), y.ToString(format, formatProvider), z.ToString(format, formatProvider));
> }
> ```

The default [Fixed-point format specifier (`F1`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#fixed-point-format-specifier-f) rounds the output to `1` fixed digit.

if you want the exact values use e.g.

```
Debug.Log(verticiesList[0].ToString("G"));
```

the [General format specifier (`G`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString) prints up to 7 digits for `float` values.

---

If your goal was to store and later restore values e.g. when writing the values to a file etc then rather use `G9` instead

> When used with a Single value, the "G9" format specifier ensures that the original Single value successfully round-trips.

Already needed this once for a since project.

Comment: if i have a mesh instance and i assign my vertices list to it, is it still ok?

Comment: @Mr.Banks The log and ToString is just an output with applied formatting rules. It does in no way affect your actual values in the list ;)

Comment: the "G" is a great tip!

Answer (score 3):

Using the [ToString Method Parameter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ToString.html) you can print the floats to what ever decimal place you want:

```
Debug.Log(verticalList[0].ToString("F6")); //will show 6 decimal places
```